# How to subset all rows from data frame for repeated measures

Tags: r, panel-data

The background for my question is:
I have a dataset consisting of repeated measures, one data point per row. These data are from a longitudinal study and therefore at the moment not every subject has all data points.

I would like to be able to extract all data points the meet a criteria, i.e., all repeated measures, or those with two repeated measures.

Here's a simplified example:

```
subject.id <- c( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 )
visit <- c( 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0 )
data.value <- c( 32, 35, 38, 12, 18, 24, 9, 13, 21 )
data.from.study <- data.frame( subject.id, visit, data.value )
```

which results in:

```
  subject.id visit data.value
1          0     0         32
2          0     1         35
3          0     2         38
4          1     0         12
5          1     1         18
6          1     2         24
7          2     0          9
8          2     1         13
9          3     0         21
```

So:

- Subjects 0 and 1 have baseline and two repeated measures,
- Subject 2 has the baseline measure and one repeated measure, and
- Subject 3 only has the baseline measure.

I would like to be able to selectively subset for all subjects which have two repeated measures (or one or just baseline), where all there data is included, i.e.:

```
> data.2.measures <- ??
> data.2.measures
      subject.id visit data.value
    1          0     0         32
    2          0     1         35
    3          0     2         38
    4          1     0         12
    5          1     1         18
    6          1     2         24
```

I'm able to subset for where - using this example - *visit == 2*. But then I don't see how I can also extract the data for visits 0 and 1, for those subjects with a second visit data point. Conceptually I can see that I know the subject.id and could somehow use this information, but I'm not sure then how to subset using a list. Is the *%in%* operator of potential help here?

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using `dplyr`. So you will `group_by` the `subject.id` and `filter` by the count. So in this example, it would simply be:

```
library(dplyr)

subject.id <- c( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 )
visit <- c( 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0 )
data.value <- c( 32, 35, 38, 12, 18, 24, 9, 13, 21 )
data.from.study <- data.frame( subject.id, visit, data.value )

data.from.study %>% group_by(subject.id) %>%
  filter(n() == 3)
```

which will have output:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: subject.id

  subject.id visit data.value
1          0     0         32
2          0     1         35
3          0     2         38
4          1     0         12
5          1     1         18
6          1     2         24
```

Comment: Or using base R: `indx <- with(data.from.study, ave(subject.id, subject.id, FUN = length)) == 3` and then `data.from.study[indx, ]`

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a function, here's another base R solution:

```
measures <- function(visits) {
  patients <- df1$subject.id[df1$visit %in% visits]
  df1[df1$subject.id %in% patients,]
}
```

So you can do:

```
measures(1)
  subject.id visit data.value
1          0     0         32
2          0     1         35
3          0     2         38
4          1     0         12
5          1     1         18
6          1     2         24
7          2     0          9
8          2     1         13

#and

measures(2)
  subject.id visit data.value
1          0     0         32
2          0     1         35
3          0     2         38
4          1     0         12
5          1     1         18
6          1     2         24
```

Note: I changed the name of the data frame to something smaller with `df1 <- data.from.study`